# How to using where and join in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, select, join, where-clause

I have two tables;

database tftube;
table tftube_video;

database tfmember;
table member;

```
create table member(
 no int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 member_no int,
 name varchar(15) not null 
);

create table tftube_reply(
no int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
member_no int, 
video_name varchar(100)
);
```

I need to

**1**.tfmember.member.member_no equals tftube.tftube_reply.member_no

**2**.video_name=10.

**3**.Result variables are name, no, member_no,video_name.

So I try to this way.

```
 select a.name from tfmember.member a join tftube.tftube_reply b on a.no = b.member_no where b.video_name=10;
```

but it's error 
please help me
p.s tfmember.member.member_no contains tftube.tftube_reply.member_no.

Comment: Provide the details of tftube.tftube_reply table.

Comment: The table names in your query are not the same as the table names posted. Once synched the query runs.

Comment: Oh sorry..I edited. I will write a question more carefully at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct query will be:

```
select a.name from member a join tftube_reply b on a.no = b.member_no and b.video_name='10';
```

You should learn more about query before posting to ST.
Refer below link:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/index.htm

Comment: @onOa your questions and table names is always edited. Please check my answer again and save your time.

Comment: If it's ok, plsease consider to accept the answer and vote.

Answer (score 0):

`select a.name from tfmember.member a join tftube.tftube_reply b on a.no = b.member_no where b.video_name=10;`

*You join with table a auto increment col with table b member_no and video_name is varchar type that's why use '10' in where condition*

**Correct Query**

`select a.name from tfmember.member a join tftube.tftube_reply b on a.member_no = b.member_no where b.video_name='10';`